# how to debug/fix screen crashes on startup

Tags: osx, gnu-screen

*(this is a question in reference to the OS X version of Gnu screen. I don't know if this makes any difference - and I guessed that Unix & Linux would have better screen-fu than Ask Different.)*

When I'm physically at my computer at a terminal, and I type a command like

```
screen -dRR my_session_name
```

I *can* get access to a new screen session.

While on SSH, I seem able to re-attach to sessions if they are already running:

```
screen -R my_session_name
```

but creating a new session (whether or not some other session exists, but most frustratingly when none do) will *hang*, the only way to escape being a `^Z` to push it to the background, and then an `fg` to restart the job, at which point I  am informed it has died (`Sorry, cannot contact session "processnumber.tty.hostname" again.`)

I have tried running `sudo dtruss screen` (Mac OS X's version of `strace`), but I have no idea what to look for in the (extremely verbose) output.

I am away from my machine for a while (in a different city for a few days) and I really need to start a new screen session!

my `~/.screenrc`:

```
# Set the shell to use fish:
shell "/usr/local/bin/fish"

# Make xterm scrolling work properly with screen.
# Note, this works in Terminal.app and iTerm too.
#termcapinfo xterm-256color|xterm-color|xterm|xterms|xs|rxvt ti@:te@

# Custom escape character like this:
escape ^Xx

# always create these sessions for me:
screen -t "foo" 1

# test to see if I can create new screens from SSH in any way:
#nonblock on
```

I have tried, as you can see, adding and commenting out various options to try to solve this. (just now, I've tried with both `fish` and `bash`, from both `fish` and `bash` outer sessions, with and without `noblock`, and with and without a `screen -t`.) I also see the same behaviour on very fast and very slow connections.

I would be very grateful for any of the following information:

- suggestions on finding the problem (important parts of strace/dtrace output, something else?)
- suggestions of new `.screenrc` options,
- something completely different?

am happy to post more information, but wanted to avoid the whole `dtruss` output as it's hundreds of lines long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*sideways answer, OS X-specific in this case.*

One option, and the one that I used in the end in this case, was as follows:

Use something to launch `screen` locally, which will work, and then re-attach to the session.

I wrote a python program that generates and runs an apple script program which opens a new Terminal.app window and runs the command you asked for, even when you're over SSH (obviously, the account must be logged in in a GUI on the machine itself for this to work).

It is called "osxhijack" and it's on github [here](https://github.com/joe-jordan/osxhijack). You invoke it like so:

```
hijack screen -dRR my_new_session
```

and then you can reattach straight away using:

```
screen -R my_new_session
```

If a "real" answer comes to light (i.e. if I find out what was/is wrong with my screen installation), I will update this question with a new answer.